# NullPointerException in Selenium-Maven-Cucumber Framework for WebDriver

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, pom.xml

I have 2 classes, one is BaseClass and End2EndSteps. In BaseClass I have defined property file reading, browser invoking methods. I am calling the BaseClass method from End2EndSteps class but I am getting NullPointerException. Any help here for a fellow learner. I've tried creating a new object of the BaseClass and calling the openChromeBrowser method, in that I got StackOverFlow error.

This is the BaseClass code

```
package org.example;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class BaseClass {

    public Properties properties;
    public String propertyFilePath= "src/main/resources/properties/Configuration.properties";


    public BaseClass(){
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(propertyFilePath));
            properties = new Properties();
            try {
                properties.load(reader);
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Configuration.properties not found at " + propertyFilePath);
        }
    }

    private String getDriverPath(){
        String driverPath = properties.getProperty("driverPath");
        if(driverPath!= null) return driverPath;
        else throw new RuntimeException("driverPath not specified in the Configuration.properties file.");
    }

    private String setBrowserProperties(){
        getDriverPath();
        if(getDriverPath()!=null) return System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", getDriverPath());
        else throw new RuntimeException("Browser properties not set");
    }

    public WebDriver openChromeBrowser(WebDriver driver){
        setBrowserProperties();
        if(setBrowserProperties()!=null){
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            return driver;
        }
        else throw new RuntimeException("Chrome Browser is not opened");
    }

    public long getImplicitlyWait() {
        String implicitlyWait = properties.getProperty("implicitlyWait");
        if(implicitlyWait != null) return Long.parseLong(implicitlyWait);
        else throw new RuntimeException("implicitlyWait not specified in the Configuration.properties file.");
    }

    public String getApplicationUrl() {
        String url = properties.getProperty("url");
        if(url != null) return url;
        else throw new RuntimeException("url not specified in the Configuration.properties file.");
    }
}
```

This is the End2EndSteps code

```
package stepDefinitions;

import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import org.example.BaseClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import pageObjects.HomePage;
import pageObjects.ProductListing;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class End2EndSteps {

    public WebDriver driver;
    BaseClass bS;

    @Given("User is on Home Page")
    public void user_is_on_home_page() {
        bS.openChromeBrowser(this.driver);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.252 s <<< FAILURE! - in runners.TestRunner
[ERROR] Automated End2End Tests.Customer place an order by purchasing an item from search  Time elapsed: 0.16 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at stepDefinitions.End2EndSteps.user_is_on_home_page(End2EndSteps.java:32)
        at ?.User is on Home Page(file:///C:/Project/IdeaProjects/AutomationTesting/src/test/resources/functionalTests/End2End_Test.feature:5)

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   null
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.473 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-02-28T23:08:23+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M8:test (default-test) on project AutomationTesting: 
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Project\IdeaProjects\AutomationTesting\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

This is the property file:

```
url="https://shop.demoqa.com"
driverPath="C:\\mine\\Automation_JARS_Drivers\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe"
implicitlyWait=10
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the *WebDriver* instance *`driver`* within ***End2EndSteps*** file as:

```
public WebDriver driver;
```

But when you create *BaseClass* object *`bS`*, within ***BaseClass*** have no idea about the *`driver`* instance. Hence you see *NullPointerException*.

Comment: I declared the WebDriver in BaseClass and remove the WebDriver argument in OpenChromeBrowser method and removed in End2EndSteps class also, still NullPointerException is coming.
````
public WebDriver driver;
public WebDriver openChromeBrowser(){
        setBrowserProperties();
        if(setBrowserProperties()!=null){
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            return driver;
        }
        else throw new RuntimeException("Chrome Browser is not opened");
    }
````
````
public void user_is_on_home_page() {
        bS.openChromeBrowser();
    }
````